# Android, HTTP POST request to Drupal back-end

Tags: android, drupal, drupal-7, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a problem while trying to implement a communication by means of HTTP request.
More precisely, I've used the Volley library and this is my client-side request:

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://mysite/mydrupalservice",
                                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                Log.w("CheckinFragment. POST call, RESPONSE:", String.valueOf(response));
                                            }
                                        },
                                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                VolleyLog.e("CheckinFragment. POST call, ERROR:", String.valueOf(error));
                                            }
                                        }){

                                    @Override
                                    protected Map<String,String> getParams()
                                    {
                                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                        params.put("action", "something");
                                        params.put("access_token", "something");
                                        params.put("activity", "1");
                                        return params;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
                                    {
                                        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                                        headers.put("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
                                        headers.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
                                        return headers;
                                    }
                                };

                                // add the request object to the queue to be executed
                                Controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);`
```

This code is correctly executed from Android-side, but the response received is the following:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://mysite/myservice
android.volley.AuthFailureError.
```

I've tried to use http://httpbin.org/ to test my client-side code and it works correctly.

So, I thought that the problem might be server-side.
If I try to perform a HTTP request with POST parameters, using for example Firefox's extension Poster, I receive the correct response from the server.

Looking at 401 error code, I thought that the service previously created on Drupal would require an authentication by the user, but that option was previously disabled.

I don't know how to solve this problem, anyone does?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: Do you have another "simple" method on your Drupal backend? Maybe try to call a GET method first to see if error occurs.

Comment: Yes, I have several methods. All of them are used for HTTP Get requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use url encoded? For example:

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // try this
        return params;
    }
```

Comment: I've solved my problem using your suggestion, but also modifying the "Request parsing" option in the service created on drupal, in order to accept "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" input type.
I can't understand why drupal didn't accept the "application/json" input type

Comment: Glad to have helped. It probably would have worked if you used JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest.